# Kentico - Form Control Drop-down List & SQL Query

Tags: kentico

I couldn't make the title clearer, but here's what I need help with.

I have a custom page type [1] for Leaders which includes 2 fields: *Name*, and *Title*. This holds the list of all leaders at the company.

I have another custom page type [2] for Speaking Events, which includes a field called *Speaker* to display the speaker's name and title. This field was set up as a drop-down list with data source from a SQL Query to query the Leaders data in [1].

```
Select LeadersID, Name, Title from co_leaders order by Name
```

I got it work fine - the drop-down displays a list of Name. However, what I wanted to display in the drop-down option is: Name, Title (not just Name) like below so that I only pick one and have both Name and Title. Is it possible to do this?

```
John Doe, CEO
Jane Doe, CFO
```

Hope it's clear and thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the SQL you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT LeadersID, Name + ', ' + Title FROM co_leaders ORDER BY Name
```

You need to do a concatenation of the column values (`Name` and `Title`), as opposed to **selecting** the columns separately.

EDIT: This is assuming that `Name` and `Title` are not nullable fields.
If there is a `NULL` value in any of the concatenated fields, the end value will be `NULL`. In this case, you will need to use `COALESCE` (or an equivalent function) to define an alternative value. For example:

```sql
SELECT LeadersID, Name + ', ' + COALESCE(Title, 'Member') FROM co_leaders ORDER BY Name
```